# Remove line break from string

Tags: c#, html, css

I am converting text file into html in C# environment. What I did was changing the extension .txt to .html and replace all the `Writeline` with `<p>` tags. The output file prints out everything but there's a line break in between two lines. Any suggestion?

```
checkingWriter = File.AppendText(checkingPath);
checkingWriter.WriteLine("<p>Checking SF data<p>");
```

> Checking results for product: d02100
>   Checking SF data

Comment: Yeah.. suggestion would be not to use `WriteLine`. The `WriteLine` method  
writes a line terminator to the text string or stream. Assuming you're using StreamWriter here's [some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get you started.

Comment: You probably have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: `WriteLine` > `Write`

Comment: @SLaks Not sure you read the post? No xss here

Comment: @Matt Do you know what XSS is? There's a possibility of XSS as we do not know where those 'text files' are coming from meaning they could contain malicious code. This is a precautionary comment as a heads-up to the OP.

Comment: `checkingPath.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty)`

Comment: When you say “the output file prints out” do you mean you are opening the file is a web browser like Chrome? Or are you looking at it in a text editor like Visual Studio?

Comment: @DourHighArch yes Chrome!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the HTML view showing empty space between paragraphs, then that is simply what the `<p>` tag does by default in all browsers. The rule is: if the `<p>` has content, then show that content *and* show a bit of empty space before the next element renders. That empty space is called vertical margin.

You can change this behaviour by including this very small CSS definition: `p { margin: 0 }`.

Demo:

```css
p { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<p>Checking SF data<p>
<p>Checking other data<p>
<p>Checking more data<p>
<p>Checking final data<p>
```

And even though most browsers will auto-close `<p>` (for historic reasons), it is better to *close them yourself by putting `</p>` at the end of each paragraph*:

```css
p { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<p>Checking SF data</p>
<p>Checking other data</p>
<p>Checking more data</p>
<p>Checking final data</p>
```

And as a response to your comment, it is always possible to include CSS definitions by means of a `<style>` tag inside the document like this.

```
<style type="text/css">
    p { margin: 0 }
</style>
```

You can add a `WriteLine()` command to output it.

Comment: a `p` isn't a self closing tag and that is invalid html which would leave you open to how the browser interprets it - if you inspect the elements, in this case chrome is clever enough to close them. Also I think OP is wanting the `p`s to be on the same line rather than worried about the space between the lines

Comment: I can't do the p{margin:0}, because I have checkingWriter.WriteLine("<p>Checking SF data <p>") instead <p>Checking SF data<p>